# How do i write html data into file in python, Error is "IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

Tags: python, html, cgi

My html consist of firstname, lastname, age and gender. I am fetching out the values from it and wants to write those value in a file. However i am getting an error of IOError: Bad file descriptor.

On my html page, on submit click i am calling this test.py, which should write data into file name "copy.txt"

My test.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi

print "Content- type : text/html\n"
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

Fname = form.getvalue('firstname')
Lname = form.getvalue('lastname')
Age = form.getvalue('age')
Gender = form.getvalue('gender')

f = open("copy","w")
for data in f:
    f.write("Fname")
    f.write("Lname")
    f.write("age")
    f.write("gender")
f.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    for data in f:
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: you must use `f = open("copy.txt","w")`

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: cannot find the solution in the above link

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: could you lease help. i am not understanding the above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, its difficult to say what the problem is because you do not provide a traceback:

```
import cgi

print "Content- type : text/html\n"
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

Fname = form.getvalue('firstname')
Lname = form.getvalue('lastname')
Age = form.getvalue('age')
Gender = form.getvalue('gender')

with open('copy.txt', 'w') as f:
    for data in f:
        f.write("Fname")
        f.write("Lname")
        f.write("age")
        f.write("gender")
```

If you cannot use the `with` keyword, then you are going to have to close it normally:

```
f = open('copy.txt', 'w')
for data in f:
    f.write("Fname")
    f.write("Lname")
    f.write("age")
    f.write("gender")
f.close()
```

Comment: i cannot use 'with' keyword. its reserved in python 2.6

Comment: Also updated traceback error

Comment: @johnjohn Take a look at the update, and this is a duplicate.

Comment: still the same error: Bad File Descriptor......should i put my html code too >??